# HTML/CSS analyzer of Firefox environment

Tags: firefox, html, css

I know that I can modify the Firefox' look using the `chrome/userChrome.css` file. I know some tag IDs as `#topbar`. However, I'd like to modify things further. Therefore the question: Is it possible to see the "source-code" of the menus and stuff, of at least a complete list of `#tags` that allow the modifications.

Specs: Firefox 26.0, Fedora 20, MATE 1.6.1

Comment: You can view the source code of the whole project [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives).

Comment: @ChrisCooney Looks promising, thanks. I'll explore it and let you know whether it's sufficient for me.